# ¿Cómo puedo implementar este código si la url tiene id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Al colocar una url con id cómo esta `isActive('/ejemplo/{{ejemplo.id}}')` no funciona.

```js
app.controller('ActiveNavCtrl', ['$scope','$location', function($scope,$location){
    $scope.isActive = function(destination){
      return destination === $location.path();
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<a ng-href="/Ejemplo" ng-class="{active: isActive('/ejemplo')}">Ejemplo</a>
```

Comment: porque usas ejemplo.id, acaso "ejemplo" este es el nombre del controller ? O le estas definiendo un allias al controller? porque no solo usas {{id}} si es que asignas el id al $scope

Comment: Te has planteado la opcion de la E mayuscula? que te devuelve $location.path() ?

Comment: Has intentado: isActive('/ejemplo/' + {{ejemplo.id}} )?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini En realidad es {{item.id}} "item" es el nombre de mi ng-repeat="item in items"

Comment: @KN_ al hacerlo cómo dices me manda este error: [https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=)&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=27&p3=%5B%7Bshow:]

Comment: @AdrianoJosué, has probado esto?  isActive('/ejemplo/' + item.id)

Comment: @jjimenez Google Chrome no me lanza ningún error pero tampoco funciona, la etiqueta <a> normalmente esta en "visivility: hidden;" y con este código lo que hago es que cuando este en la url con id cambie a visivility: visible; pero no funciona excepto que coloque el id en concreto ejemplo: isActive('/news/1') el "1" es un id, en ese caso si funciona. no comprendo que pasa :(

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres hacer es que el enlace se muestre o no dependiendo de si el método `isActive` devuelve `true`, es más correcto usar `ngIf`[1] o `ngShow` de esta forma:

```
<a ng-href="/Ejemplo" ng-if="isActive('/ejemplo' + item.id)}">Ejemplo</a>
```

A parte de esto, varias cosas:

**Sobre ng-class**

Cuando usabas `isActive('/ejemplo/{{item.id}}')` no te funcionaba por que no es una expresión válida. Echa un vistazo a lo que para AngularJS es una Expresión [2]. Lo correcto sería: `isActive('/ejemplo/' + item.id)`

**Sobre $location.path()**

Si estás usando `ui-router` para las enrutar tu aplicación, podrías usar $state.current.name y $stateParams para saber el estado y los parámetros de éste.

[1] https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

[2] https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression